# python port scanner snippet return unexpected result

Tags: python

i am setting up a local webserver using port 2000 in a mac machine and try to use the snippet below to scan the open port, i would expect it return port 2000 as open but it wasn't.  may i know if i missed anything?

```
python -m http.server 2000
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)    
server = '127.0.0.1' 
def pscan(server, port):
    try:
        s.connect((server , port))
        return True
    except:
        return False

for x in range(1, 2100):
    if pscan(server, x):
        print(f'Port {x} is open!')
    else:
        print(f'Port {x} is close!')
```

result:
Port 1998 is close!
Port 1999 is close!
Port 2000 is close!
Port 2001 is close!
Port 2002 is close!
Port 2003 is close!
Port 2004 is close!
Port 2005 is close!
Port 2006 is close!
Port 2007 is close!
Port 2008 is close!
Port 2009 is close!
Port 2010 is close!

Comment: You'll have to show us `pscan`

Comment: opps, my bad, i've edited my question :)

Comment: Thank you. So, it seems that your `server` is a string, not a socket object.

Comment: s is a socket object.  s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

Comment: Assuming that you create the `s` socket before you make the `connect` call, this would still raise an exception because the `s` in `(s, p)` would be a socket

Comment: ahh...i updated my code in my question but the result remain the same